# ORA-00922: missing or invalid option Error on Oracle table creation

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE Job History
    (JobID INT REFERENCES Jobs(JobID),
    IDNum INT REFERENCES Employees(IDNum),
    StartDate DATE
    );
```

throws me this error: `ORA-00922: missing or invalid option`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is space in the table name then it should be wrapped in the double quotes as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE "JOB HISTORY" (
    JOBID       INT REFERENCES JOBS ( JOBID ),
    IDNUM       INT REFERENCES EMPLOYEES ( IDNUM ),
    STARTDATE   DATE
);
```

It is not good practice to include space in the table name. Instead, You can use the _ to separate the words in the table like: `JOB_HISTORY`